# xquery with xpath and HTML

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xquery

I have to produce an xquery file using normalize text and lower case Xpath function.  (that is the page which includes the schema that my query must process: http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/docs/URG/bnctags.html) I must put it in a table and I do not know who to produce a HTML table with xquery and I do not know also who to link xquery with xpath.

(That is the specification of my exercise)
Produce a .xquery file containing a XQuery FLWOR expression which returns all the
occurrences of the word 'has' in the collection of files, together with the word which comes next in the sentence in each case. The resulting list should be formatted as a HTML table, with each row containing the two words in their own cells, e.g.:

```
Target Successor
has    there
has    n't
has    n't
... ...
```

Comment: Just write an HTML table with one row. Then add a `{` before the row, and a `}` after the row. Then add something like `for $x in collection()/whatever/elem return ` in front of the row. Use braces again within the row to add xpath expressions to whatever info you want to show in the row about $x. XPath is integral part of XQuery, so you don't need to link it. Good luck..

Comment: <tr><td>{normalize-space($w/text())}</td></tr>                                   thanks                                                                         now how i may find the word "has" and present its following siblings in descending order?                                                                     thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following, with the main thing being to figure out the proper pattern match.
    let 
    $seek := "has",
    $pattern := concat($seek,"(\s?[^\s])")
    return <table>
    <tr><th>Target</th><th>Successor</th>
    {
       for $item in //text()[contains(.,'has')] 
         let $match := string($item)
         return <tr>
         <td>{replace($match,$pattern,"$1")}</td>
         <td>{replace($match,$pattern,"$2")}</td>
       </tr>
    }
    </table>